# How to get current site details in alfresco repository?

Tags: share, alfresco

I am trying to get current site name in alfresco repository side webscript. I tried a couple of ways.

```
page.url.templateArgs.site - //it wont work as its share side stuff.
```

Do anyone has any idea on this?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question said you are in a repository tier web script. The repository has a service called SiteService. The SiteService allows you, among other things, to fetch a site by its ID. The getSite() method returns a Site object. Learn more about the SiteService and the Site object in the [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/references/API-JS-SiteserviceObject.html).

Comment: I passed site name in getSite(siteId) to get site object for further manipulation.

Comment: I want to get the current site name in javascript. Also I have already added siteService but don't have current site name. Any idea?

Comment: @nikhil84 please start a new question and provide context regarding what you are trying to do and where your code is running

Comment: Does the `getSite()` not apply in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953728/how-can-i-create-a-file-in-the-same-folder-node-in-alfresco) similar instance?

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco Repository [Webscripts Root Objects](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/references/API-JS-rootscoped.html) won't give you that. You will get this from the Surf based Alfresco Share [Root Objects](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/references/APISurf-url.html)

Comment: I tried but it seems these objects are available only on share side but not on repository side. What i am trying to do is to get all users associated to a site in authority picker.

Comment: If you're driving your webscript from the Share application, then you can define your webscript to accept a siteName variable, and pass it through your service call.